# Install local RPM with regex or glob filename using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write an ansible playbook which installs some RPMs for me after they have been copied to a known location by a Jenkins job. The problem is, I'm not sure how to get the name of the RPM to install without hard coding it.

Here is what I have now:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
  - { role: some_role, artifacts: "{{ rpm_path }}/prefix_.*.rpm" }
```

In this case, `rpm_path` would be something like:

```
"/home/jenkins/workspace/rpm_install/artifacts"
```

The role that is called in this example handles the yum install part:

```
- name: Install RPMs
  yum: name={{item}} state=present
  with_items:
    - "{{ artifacts }}"
```

I'd rather not have to hard code RPM names since they come from Jenkins and they are always different. But is there a way either through the yum module, or when I call the role where the regular expression or glob can be interpreted so the full path (rpm name included) is handed to yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [with_fileglob](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id4) insted of with_items, something like

```
- name: Install RPMs
  yum: name="{{item}}" state=present
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{ artifacts }}"
```